# closest(elem) is not returning as expected - returning init[elem..] instead of elem

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following setup

HTML:

```
<div class="prod-inner">
  <div class="number-wrapper">
      <input type="text" name="updates[]" id="testID"   value="1"  >
  </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.number-wrapper input[id=testID]').closest('prod-inner');
```

expected to return the actual div like so:

```
   <div class="prod-inner">
      <div class="number-wrapper">
          <input type="text" name="updates[]" id="testID"   value="1"  >
      </div>
    </div>
```

but instead it is returning this:

```
    init [div.prod-inner, prevObject: init(1), context: document, selector: ".number-wrapper input[id=updates_36213941315].closest(.prod-inner)"]
```

Comment: `.closest('prod-inner');` should be `.closest('.prod-inner');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the element by using class in closest. It doesn't return automatically to be a class, because jquery won't know if it is closest of class or id or some other element object:

```
$('.number-wrapper input[id="testID"]').closest('.prod-inner');
// wrap with double quotes ^^   | class selector ^.
```

---

Furthermore, you can directly use the id since it's unique:

```
$('#testID').closest('.prod-inner');
```

---

If you have dynamic id generated like I can see `id=updates_36213941315` , then you may use [attribute contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

```
$('[id*="36213941315"]').closest('.prod-inner');
```

Or, [start with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/),

```
$('[id^="updates_"]').closest('.prod-inner');
```